# Is there a way to store values, have vba search for the values within a column and paste a different set of text depending on the value?

Tags: excel, vba

Just incase the title hasn't described this properly. So I'd like to store some a load of values in VBA (probably the first problem as I wasn't sure if I could store them as a list or an array properly), have it search for these values within a column and paste a different result in a different column depending on what was in the original column.

For example:

Column A
Rich          Standard      Bumpers       Video Other   Snap Ad       Text Tweet

Column B Display Display Video Video Social Social

So far I've made an IF statement but it's going to be quite a long bit of code that I'd rather not have if this is possible without, but this is a small amount of what it looks like because it's a beastly bit of code with everything I need inside of it. Just incase it's relevant LastRow is just to make the code do it to the last row within the sheet that has text. Thanks in advance! :)

```
Sheets("GATE Digital Data").Select
For Each Cell In Range("M5:M" & LastRow)
    If InStr(Cell.Value, "Standard") Then
        Cell.Offset(0, -5).Value = "Display"
    ElseIf InStr(Cell.Value, "Video Other") Then
        Cell.Offset(0, -5).Value = "Video"
```

[Example of current outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTR5o.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be easier to understand what you want to achieve by showing us an example of the required output. Please read [repro] and use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to show us your data - Did you try to use formulas?

Comment: I've added an image of the current outcome with what I have, this is for work so I don't want to be pasting the whole worksheet. I didn't use a formula but I might look into using that and storing it in the macro I've made as an alternative

Comment: Propably you misunderstood what I meant: You should show your data and your **expected** output - not what you have achieved. Furthermore it really helps if you paste those data as markdown within the question - then someone who wants to help you only needs to copy those data - instead of typing them from an image ... I know, all that means work on your side - but that is what you should do to get an answer that fits to your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a lookup table and a formula to do it.

[image]

I've used three different formula - first one is for 365.  The others will work in almost any version (remove the `IFERROR` if you're in 2003 or earlier - think it came in with 2007).

`=XLOOKUP(D2,Table1[Original],Table1[Use],"Not Found")`
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,Table1,2,FALSE),"Not Found")`
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Use],MATCH(D4,Table1[Original],0)),"Not Found")`

If you don't want to use a table you'll have to adjust your ranges if you add anything to the list:

`=XLOOKUP(D2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7,"Not Found")`
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$7,2,FALSE),"Not Found")`
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7,MATCH(D4,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,0)),"Not Found")`

A VBA solution could be:

```
Public Function MyUDF(Target As Range) As Variant

    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Rich", "Standard"
            MyUDF = "Display"
        Case "Bumpers", "Video Other"
            MyUDF = "Video"
        Case "Snap Ad", "Text Tweet"
            MyUDF = "Social"
        Case Else
            MyUDF = CVErr(xlErrValue) 'Return a #VALUE! error.
    End Select

End Function
```

This could be used in a worksheet as `=MyUDF(E1)` or within a procedure.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4")
        Debug.Print MyUDF(Cell) 'Case Else would return "Error 2015"
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this Darren! This might have to be an alternative by using the second bits of code you've posted as I'd rather not store this in a table and have it all on a different sheet away from the main one.

Comment: Have added a VBA solution.

Comment: Thank you very much Darren. It's taken me until today to implement it correctly but I've finally got it to work as intended, I appreciate the help a lot!